# Jquery get values from json into select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json array which looks like this

```
[{
"": "Select your State/Region"
}, {
"BAL": "Balkh"
}, {
"BAM": "Bamian"
}]
```

I am trying to get the values out of it using jquery, but i can't seem to loop through.

This is what I've tried

```
var value = $(this).val();
var url = '{{ route('getstatesjson') }}';
 $.getJSON(url, { state: value }, function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {

    }
 });
```

but i can't seem to pull any of the objects out.  The idea is that i can use the first value as the value and the second value as the text in the select.

Comment: I think you should try JSON.parse to get the value

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Took me a while to come back to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
 $.getJSON(url, { state: value }, function(obj) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(obj,function(key,value){
      $.each(value,function(k,v){
        html +="<option value='"+k+"'>"+v+"</option>";
      });
    });
    $('put select-box id or class').html(html);
 });
```

***DEMO EXAMPLE:-***

```js
obj = [{
" ": "Select your State/Region"
}, {
"BAL": "Balkh"
}, {
"BAM": "Bamian"
}];
var html = '';
$.each(obj,function(key,value){
  $.each(value,function(k,v){
    html +="<option value='"+k+"'>"+v+"</option>";
  });
});
$('#updateOptions').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="updateOptions"></select>
```

Note:- I think `"": "Select your State/Region"` need to be `" ": "Select your State/Region"` so that value for this option become empty like `value=" "`